# App-V 5.0 package load query

Tags: javascript, appv

Firstly, I should say I know very little about App-V, all I need to find out is if this is possible.

We have 2 versions of IE9 installed on our enterpise desktop environment.
A standard basic IE and a App-V package version which includes the TruView plugin.

The TruView version is run by using a command line like this ...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" {url} /appvve:5E44A6AD-03AA-456E-888B-6E6800ACE354_77922666-E58F-441B-8510-35D569BF88CF
```

What I need to be able to do is load an HTML page in the TruView version of the browser if it needs to use the TruView plugin.

Obviously I can't run it as a command line from JavaScript for security reasons, but since it appears to be a command line switch which causes the plugin to be loaded within the default IE browser, is there a way to load the plugin package from JavaScript?

As I say, I just need to know if it is possible so I can persue the problem. If not then I can tell them we need to find another way around it.

Answer (score 0):

(I suspect you have your answer by now, but:)
The easiest way we've found to do something like this is to include a .EXE INSIDE the App-V files.  The client will detect the .EXE and cause it to launch within the virtual environment...

So we built a very simple .EXE initially that recieved command-line arguments (the URL) and executed them.  Because the .EXE is instantiated within the bubble, the http:// or URL calls are passed to IE within the bubble - so it'll see the installed ActiveX controls you've got in the App-V.

Have a look here: https://benjiappfactory.wordpress.com/2015/07/12/delivering-old-jres-or-activex-controls-in-bubbles/

I'm still re-writing the source so that I can release it publicly (and confirming I'm elminated the bugs I've introduced with the new engine - gone from AHK to AU3) but if interested I can publish it in a week or so